# Change default monitor screen in GRUB 2

Tags: grub, monitors

Recently my notebook screen died and I started using an external VGA monitor. When my computer  boots the monitor is off until GRUB 2 starts the OS. Is it possible to make GRUB 2 display its menu in the external monitor?

Comment: I have the same problem. Both linux and windows use the external monitor but I cannot see the grub menu. Did you find a solution in the mean time?

Comment: @Giorgio, I couldn't find a solution, sorry.

Comment: Another problem I have is that I cannot install a new OS: e.g. the Debian installation disk also starts on the laptop screen and so I am stuck with the operating systems that are already installed (which were installed before the screen broke). If I find a solution I will post it.

Comment: @Giorgio, try using a live CD in another computer and to memorize the keystrokes to get to the desktop environment. Then, attach your notebook to an external monitor and repeat the keystrokes.

Answer (score 1):

This should work if you have access to BIOS:

There is usually a configuration option in BIOS to select default output device on bootup. You should be able to select your external VGA port instead of your laptop's display (port).

Comment: I still have access to the BIOS configuration but as my notebook screen is dead I won't be able to see the BIOS options.

Comment: Not all notebooks have this option. Most consumer machines don't.

Comment: "Most consumer machines don't" sounds very opinionated. It is supported by Intel HD chips at least.

Comment: My bios, for one, does not have that option. Can we get an answer for how to change the monitor GRUB chooses in software?

Answer (score 0):

Used Multisystem on a USB loaded with Parrot 4.6 (not later!).
Laptop had SecureBoot disabled, was able to boot only from this usb.
On usb boot/startup, a part of the startup is displayed on the VGA monitor.
On Right Click(RC) on screen to start Launcher(>Launcher) to find previously stored file on the harddrive, titled
"xrandr --output VGA-1 --same-as LVDS-1"  & its contents.
RC>Terminal
RC>paste "xrandr --output VGA-1 --same-as LVDS-1"
press Return.
This causes whatever the display output for the laptop screen (LVDS-1) to be sent to VGA-1.
This was worked "blindly" on laptop with broken/missing LVDS-1.

More permanently, a competent Linux person (I wish I was!) possibly can
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub/grub.d/parrot.cfg
find
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash noautomount"
change to
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="video=VGA-1:e video=LVDS-1:D"
lenovo g580, no bios or windows access.